# Set custom attribute to exif android not working

Tags: java, android, flutter, exif

I am currently facing a real issue while trying to set custom attributes to my image EXIF on android.

I have the following lines :

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(path);
exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_PLANE_X_RESOLUTION, "330");
```

But it simply doesn't work. I have tried with many different tags from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#setAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) but none is working.

Am i not understanding something correctly ?
I have also tried :

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(path);
exifInterface.setAttribute("FocalPlaneXResolution", "330");
```

I also need to save the values of `Yaw`, `Pitch` and `Roll` in the exif, should the following be working ?

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(path);
exifInterface.setAttribute("Yaw", "0.3");
```

I am saving the attributes using `exifInterface.saveAttributes()`

EDIT :

I have printed the `EXIF` of the image right after the `saveAttributes()` :

```
I/flutter (12318): EXIF FOR FILE : /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.android/projectName/2022-10-14-11-51-07-810.jpg
I/flutter (12318): Image YResolution: 72
I/flutter (12318): Image XResolution: 72
I/flutter (12318): Image ImageWidth: 1920
I/flutter (12318): Image Model: CPH1931
I/flutter (12318): Image Make: OPPO
I/flutter (12318): Image Software: unknown-user 10 QKQ1.200209.002 unknown release-keys
I/flutter (12318): Image ImageLength: 1080
I/flutter (12318): Image YCbCrPositioning: Centered
I/flutter (12318): Image ExifOffset: 260
I/flutter (12318): Image Orientation: 90
I/flutter (12318): Image ResolutionUnit: Pixels/Inch
I/flutter (12318): Image DateTime: 2022:10:14 11:51:08
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ExifVersion: 0220
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ApertureValue: 169/100
I/flutter (12318): EXIF SceneType: 63
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ExposureProgram: Unidentified
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ColorSpace: sRGB
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ExifImageLength: 1080
I/flutter (12318): EXIF BrightnessValue: -27/25
I/flutter (12318): EXIF DateTimeOriginal: 2022:10:14 11:51:08
I/flutter (12318): EXIF FlashPixVersion: 0100
I/flutter (12318): EXIF SubSecTimeOriginal: 199953
I/flutter (12318): EXIF WhiteBalance: Auto
I/flutter (12318): Interoperability InteroperabilityIndex: R98
I/flutter (12318): EXIF InteroperabilityOffset: 726
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ExposureMode: Auto Exposure
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ExposureTime: 1/25
I/flutter (12318): EXIF Flash: Flash did not fire, compulsory flash mode
I/flutter (12318): EXIF SubSecTime: 341
I/flutter (12318): EXIF FNumber: 9/5
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ExifImageWidth: 1920
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ISOSpeedRatings: 361
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ComponentsConfiguration: 636363
I/flutter (12318): EXIF FocalLengthIn35mmFilm: 0
I/flutter (12318): EXIF SubSecTimeDigitized: 199953
I/flutter (12318): EXIF DateTimeDigitized: 2022:10:14 11:51:08
I/flutter (12318): EXIF ShutterSpeedValue: 4643/1000
I/flutter (12318): EXIF MeteringMode: CenterWeightedAverage
I/flutter (12318): EXIF FocalLength: 4047/1000
I/flutter (12318): EXIF SceneCaptureType: Standard
I/flutter (12318): EXIF LightSource: Unknown
I/flutter (12318): EXIF SensingMethod: 0
```

The custom tag `Yaw` didn't seem to be registered, and i have added another existing tag `TAG_FOCAL_PLANE_X_RESOLUTION` that is also missing while setting correctly.

EDIT : I have found that writing custom attributes that do not exists in the documentation will never work and fail silently... So `Yaw` in my issue description will never be written.

Comment: You set an attrbute on the exifinterface. But after that you have to update the exif header in the image file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't know what it means, could you elaborate please or give an example of the "exif header" in the image file ?

Comment: Your image file, probably a jpg file, contains an exif header. The class ExifInterfae reads this exif header. You changed the exif info in memory in the ExifInterface instance. But now you have to update the file with the new info. I see no code for that. Or lets say i think that saveAttributes() is not updating the file. (But maybe i'm mistaken, never done that). What is type of `path` and how does it look like?

Comment: `path` is the local path of the image in the `temporary` directory, and indeed a `.jpg`. 
I have access to this file if that's your question, what do you want me to do ?
I will give an example later if you really need it but i am not sure why it matters. 
Indeed i have not updated the file with the new info because i don't know how to do so :/ I thought the `exif.saveAttributes()` was doing this job but i guess i was wrong..

Comment: `I have access to this file` You were able to read it. But have you permission to write it? Check before with File.canWrite(). I also do think now that saveAttributes() should update the file.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer and thanks for your time. Yes i have the permission to write it because i save it myself in the external storage directory if the user chose to do so (in his phone's gallery) AND inside the app document directory.

Comment: I edit the question with a new test i have made.

Comment: `I have printed the EXIF of the image right after the saveAttributes() :` I think you mean: I have printed the exif tags of exifinfo right after the saveAttributes(). (You did not create a new exifinfo from the saved file and printed then)

Comment: yes exactly sorry for my sentences.

Comment: Strange that not all tags are there when you try to read them from the newly created file. Oh no. Not newly created.. you write to the original file!?

Comment: `When copying a file to another place, the exif is not kept at all.` Well than i wonder how you copy a file. Using an intermediate bitmap or so? The wrong approach. A normal file copy preserves all bytes

Comment: I edit the question with the requested information !

Comment: I have found the issue for the "copying a file removes some exif params", this was coming from a compression library i was using. 
The main/real issue is about custom tags not being saved.